# Optimal keep data inside program

Tags: c#, class, struct

I have a table which it has 2000 row. This tables "name" columns are static. But Others is dinamic. The table follow as :

[image]

Can i keep this table inside program? Which format must use? (Class,list, datatable, struct Json or etc.).

I'll search and update on table in future...

Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing the exact needs of your program I would recommend keeping it on a JSON file. What happens if you close the program and reopen??

Comment: Close and reopen program change nothing (don't change anything). 
I need rapidly search because i algorithm is mixed. There are more condition. And i think datatable or list may be more fast from JSON.

Comment: 2000 rows is *nothing*. You can choose whatever data structure best serves your needs, there's nothing to worry about in terms of performance.

Comment: Robert, I think  search and update 2000 rows at the same time make a problem me. Process going low. İs it right?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily put your row data into a `MyRow` class with `Id`, `Position`, `Weight` and `FullEmp` properties and then put those row objects into a list of rows like `List<MyRow>`.

Performance considerations largely depend on what you want to do with your data. How often do you read it? How often do you change it? How often do you insert, append or remove rows? Which properties do you access during your search?

A list is a good starting point that you can use until you find out that the performance is unsatisfactory for your usecase.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think so. 
You can easily put your row data into a MyRow class with Id, Position, Weight and FullEmp properties and then put those row objects into a list of rows like List<MyRow>.
But i use this data frequently. Because when i use search any row i check 4 or more condition for this row. If all conditions answers are true i update 100 -125 row at same time.